# Insert String every n lines, while also resetting line counter at desired string

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed, command

I need to read a text file and insert a string every n lines, but also have the line counter restart when I come across a header string.

Line repeating working every 3 lines using code:

sed '0~3 s/$/\nINSERT/g' < INPUT/PATH/FILE_NAME.txt > OUTPUT/PATH/FILE_NAME.txt

I cannot seem to find how to restart counter when line=Header... I have also tried using a shell command with much less success.

ex. input:

```
 1. Header Line Here 
 2. dog 
 3. cat
 4. fish
 5. pony
 6. horse
 8. bird
 7. Header Line Here
 8. whale
 9. Header Line Here 
 10. shark
 11. lizard
 12. dolphin
```

required output:

```
 1. Header Line Here 
 2. dog 
 3. cat
 4. INSERT
 5. fish
 6. pony
 7. horse
 8. INSERT
 9. bird
 10. Header Line Here
 11. whale
 12. Header Line Here 
 13. shark
 14. lizard
 15. INSERT
 16. dolphin
```

Comment: Is that line numbers part of the original input file?

Comment: No, the line numbers were just added to represent when to insert my string. All lines are variable except the "Header Line"

Comment: I suspect there are some typos as the output file contains certain lines which the input doesnt contain, like `9. bird`( in output)

Comment: Yes you're correct, sorry for the typo... First time posting and I couldn't get the format correct so I manually typed the input/output

Comment: Please do correct the sample input and output as it gives a wrong information to people who try to solve them. Also the pattern doesnt follow throught the file. I assume that you where trying to have `INSERT` at every 4th line

Comment: Where has bird come from ?

Comment: I have corrected the data in the questions, bird missing was a typo. I am currently testing with the examples given

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Assuming that you need to have `INSERT` at every 4th line ( taken the value of n as 4)*

This can very easily implemented using `awk`

```
awk '/Header/{flag=1} !(flag++%4){print "INSERT"}1'
```

---

**What it does?**

- `/Header/{flag=1}` If the line matches the pattern `Header`, sets the `flag` as `1`
- `!(flag++%4){print "INSERT"}` short of  `flag%4 == 0` then `print INSERT`
- `1` Is always true, takes the default action to print the entire record/line ( Another `awk` idiom )

---

**Test**

```
$ cat input
Header Line Here 
dog 
cat
fish
pony
horse
bird
fish
Header Line Here
whale
Header Line Here 
shark
lizard
dolphin

$ awk '/Header/{flag=1} !(flag++%4){print "INSERT"}1' input
Header Line Here 
dog 
cat
INSERT
fish
pony
horse
bird
INSERT
fish
Header Line Here
whale
Header Line Here 
shark
lizard
INSERT
dolphin
```

Comment: Insert should be after `horse` not `bird`.

Comment: using awk '/Header/{flag=1} !(flag++%4){print "INSERT"}1' C:....input C://.....output I get the script to run on the input file, but no output file is updated and the input remains unchanged... does the above config look correct?

Comment: @JID I noticed that, but in that case it doesnt give any pattern, first Insert was after 4 lines where as the next after 3 lines

Comment: @Skonectthedots No awk doesn't do inplace editing of the file. But I hope that you get the desired output on your terminal. In which case you can use redirection so as to redirect the output to an new file as you may wish

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I don't understand your reply.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R This works though `awk '!(++x%3){print "INSERT"}/Header/{x=0}1'`

Comment: @JID Ahh sorry for that will edit in my answer. Thanks you :)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R ahh right, I think OP wants it after every 3 lines including the header lines.So the header line is line 1 of the 3.I think anyway :D

Comment: @JID I hope op must have got an idea as of how to aproach such a problem. whic would be the point than worrying :D

Comment: Yeah hopefully, also BTW i am not the one who has downvoted :(

Comment: @JID That was sad :( Anyway I will leave it here

Comment: Am trying awk '(++n==3) {print "INSERT"; n=0} (/Header/) {n=0} {print "DESTINATION LOCATION";}' >> SOURCE FILE.... the script is running in my terminal with no errors, however no file is created or updated

Comment: @Skonectthedots But didn't you miss an input file? Also note that you not printing the lines from the input file as there print statement to do so

Comment: I am using awk '(++n==3) {print "INSERT"; n=0} (/Header/) {n=0} {print}' >> INPUT.txt and I get the desired output in my terminal, but when I use awk '(++n==3) {print "INSERT"; n=0} (/Header/) {n=0} {print > "OUTPUT.txt"}' INPUT.txt the txt file is only updated with the input data and no transformation

Comment: @Skonectthedots Because you need to redirect `print "INSERT"` as weel as `print "INSERT" > "OUTPUT.txt"`

Comment: Can you help with an example? My output refuses to write the correct information. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Skonectthedots The easiest to do would be `awk '(++n==3) {print "INSERT"; n=0} (/Header/) {n=0} {print}' INPUT.txt > output`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this pretty easily with awk:

```
awk '
  {print;++n}
  /Header Line Here/ {n=1}
  n==3 {print "INSERT";n=0}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pE'$a=1if/Header Line Here/;say"INSERT"unless$a++%3' file.txt
```